# How are is the ApiKey used in NuGet signing

Tags: nuget

NuGet.exe command-line requires an API key be available.

What does it do with the key?

(I'm looking for the low level details to help me understand the technology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ApiKey is not used for signing, it is more like a password to access the server (e.g. when you push a package).

If you install your own nuget server you can configure it to not require an ApiKey and then the clients do not have to provide one.